# How to add validation on single select picklist value in a screen component

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

I have a custom field State on the appointment object.
I have to represent States as a single select picklist on the screen component of flow.
Till here I have done!!!

Now I want to put a validation on the picklist component of the screen :
For 5 states of India, I have to through error that I am not accepting input for these 5 states .... but also I have to show these values in the picklist what to do now?

Comment: What has this to do with Apex, Aura components, triggers and Community? Have you added these tags arbitrarily? If so, please remove them. Instead you could add a Flow related tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have'Validate Input' option for picklists in Screenflow. Any validation for picklist values can be added in the Decision after the screen.

Based on the Decision the Error message has to be displayed to the user for the value which the user is selected.

For Example I have created a State Picklist with three values(Telangana,Andhra and Jammu). Now I created a decision component as below.

[image]

After this if the selected state is Telangana We will display the error screen . If not we will goahead with next operation as required

Comment: Can you please explain what validation formula I should add to decision box in order to get error for the particular input on the same screen.

Comment: We will not get on the same screen we have to add other screen for showing the error message as we are validating the input after that next button. I have added the example for the same in my answer

Comment: Business don't want second screen for the error so is there any other way to show error msg on the same screen ........... May be using apex ?

Comment: After the decision if invalid then use assignment to set a boolean to true and route back to the previous screen.   Use a conditional visibility rule to show the error message if boolean is true.  So user will only see one screen, but message will display conditionally.